# adding nested fields dynamically with parent.send(association).build instead of reflect_on_association(association).klass.new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, railscasts

I'm using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)'s fields_for and add fields dynamically with the `link_to_add_fields` method proposed by Ryan Bates ([Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2?view=asciicast)).

The Problem I have is that

`f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new`

, which is used to instantiate the model for the additional fields, creates a completely empty record (order_id is not being set), thus my delegated method results in an error.

If you instead use

`send(:line_items).build`

to instantiate the new record, it already has the parent's `id` set:

```
# order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :line_items

    def price_currency
        "USD"
    end
end

# line_item.rb
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order

    delegate :price_currency, :to => :order
end

# rails console
> order = Order.last # must be persisted
> line_item1 = order.class.reflect_on_association(:line_items).klass.new #=> #<LineItem id: nil, order_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
> line_item2 = order.send(:line_items).build #=> #<LineItem id: nil, order_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

> line_item1.price_currency #=> RuntimeError: LineItem#price_currency delegated to order.price_currency, but order is nil
> line_item2.price_currency #=> "USD"
```

My questions: Why does Ryan Bates use

`f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new`

to instantiate the model? Is using `#send` a bad thing, or is there something else I missed about the `send(association)` way?

**TL;DR:**

Can I savely replace

`f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new`

with

`f.object.send(association).build`

without problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does Ryan Bates use
>
> `f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new`
>
> to instantiate the model?

Because an object that `.accepts_nested_attributes` for a collection does not need to have the collection elements linked to it at the time of building the form. This will happen automatically later on (if you use `fields_for`). If you need the link, I don't see anything wrong with using `order.line_items.build` or `order.send(:line_items).build`.

So

> Can I safely replace
>
> `f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new`
>
> with
>
> `f.object.send(association).build`
>
> without problems?

Yes, you can.

Comment: just noticed that this is gonna fail anyway if the parent model is new, which is a possibility for this form, but thanks for clearing this up